# Pointer Class, yet not Allocated?

Tags: objective-c, memory, pointers, instance

I have been reviewing some basic Objective C notes from Kochan's excellent Objc-C book, and I noticed code in which a pointer is created from a class, but not manually allocated, e.g.:

```
//...

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
NSNumber *myNumber, *floatNumber, *intNumber;
NSInteger *myInt; 

//integer value

intNumber = [NSNumber numberWithInteger: 100];
myInt = [intNumber integerValue];
NSLog (@"%li", (long) myInt);

//...
```

Note all the instances created without the '[[class allocate] init]' so how can pointers be created without allocating memory for them?

Answer (score 1):

Methods such as `[NSNumber numberWithInteger: 100]` do allocate memory for an `NSNumber` object. This kind of a class method by convention is equivalent to `[[[NSNumber alloc] initWithInteger: 100] autorelease]`. The difference from the normal alloc/init idiom is that it has returned an object to you that you do not own. It will be freed automatically for you the next time through the run loop. Note that this difference is only present if you are not using Automatic Reference Counting (ARC). In a manual reference counting environment it is often very convenient to create temporary objects this way for use just in the routine you created them in without having to remember to `release` them later. You can read much more about Objective C memory management in Apple's [Memory Management Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000994-BAJHFBGH).

Answer (score 1):

Not knowing where your confusion lies I'll start with simple *boxes*, often called *variables*, apologies if this is too basic.

When you write:

```
NSInteger someNumber;
```

you are allocating a *box* suitable for storing an `NSINteger` and asking that this box be referred to by the name `someNumber` - the box also has another name, often called its *address* or *pointer*. So you've allocated space for an integer.

Similarly when you write:

```
NSNumber *intNumber;
```

you are allocating a *box* suitable for storing an `NSNumber *` - which is the way a specifying you want this box to contain the names (addresses) of other boxes - and asking that this box be referred to by the name `intNumber`. So you've allocated space for a pointer, what you haven't allocated is a box which stores an `NSNumber` (note no `*`) and whose *name* (or *address* or *pointer*) you can store in `intNumber`.

Now the line:

```
releasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
```

does two things. The lefthand side does exactly what the first two examples did, it allocates a box, gives it the convenient name `pool`, and this box is suitable for holding the names of boxes which hold `NSAutoreleasePool` values.

Now the righthand size is an expression which allocates, using `alloc`, a box suitable for holding `NSAutoreleasePool` values; puts a value into that box, using `init`; and then returns the *name* of the box.

Finally the assignment takes the name returned by the RHS and puts it into the box created by the LHS.

So overall the statement created *two* boxes.

Which gets us to your:

```
intNumber = [NSNumber numberWithInteger: 100];
```

Here the LHS specifies a box that has already been created. The RHS is an expression which returns the name of a box. Where was the box created whose name the RHS side returns? We can only really guess (unless we have the source of `numberWithInteger` of course), that doesn't matter - the box was created by someone at sometime and the expression returns its name. The assignment put the name of the box, which we didn't allocate, into the `intNumber` box, which we did. That's all you need to know...

well almost. If you are using ARC or GC you can stop here. If you are using MRC you need to know whether to `retain` the box, but that is another question...

HTH.

Answer (score 0):

declare `NSInteger *myInt;` to `NSInteger myInt;`